# document.getElementById('xs').clicked == true is not working

Tags: javascript, html

So I have this code to check if a button was clicked in the page and if the button was clicked change on button color to "clicked" and all the others to normal but somehow this condition is not getting true value!

```js
function SizeButtonStyle() {
  if(document.getElementById('xs').clicked == true){
    document.getElementById('xs').style.backgroundColor = "rgb(0, 35, 102)";
    document.getElementById('xs').style.backgroundColor = "white";
    document.getElementById('s').style.backgroundColor = "white";
    document.getElementById('s').style.backgroundColor = "rgb(0, 35, 102)";
    document.getElementById('m').style.backgroundColor = "white";
    document.getElementById('m').style.backgroundColor = "rgb(0, 35, 102)";
    document.getElementById('l').style.backgroundColor = "white";
    document.getElementById('l').style.backgroundColor = "rgb(0, 35, 102)";
    document.getElementById('xl').style.backgroundColor = "white";
    document.getElementById('xl').style.backgroundColor = "rgb(0, 35, 102)";
  }
}
```

```html
<button id="xs" onclick="SizeButtonStyle()" class="size_button"><b>XS</b></button>
<button id="s" onclick="SizeButtonStyle()" class="size_button"><b>S</b></button>
<button id="m" onclick="SizeButtonStyle()" class="size_button"><b>M</b></button>
<button id="l" onclick="SizeButtonStyle()" class="size_button"><b>L</b></button>
<button id="xl" onclick="SizeButtonStyle()" class="size_button"><b>XL</b></button>
```

Comment: Could you please share the documentation where you have found the `clicked` property of a DOM element?

Comment: There is no 'clicked' property. Not sure why you are treating buttons like radio buttons. You can style a radio button to look like a button using a label. If you are really going to stick with this styling of a button, use a class, there is no reason to add and remove tons of styles. That is a coding nightmare to maintain.

Comment: Do you realize you are setting background color to one thing and next line setting background color to another?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass [*`this`*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this) keyword to the function and refer that inside the function to check the attribute `id`. You also probably want to change the *color* and *backgroundColor* of elements:

```js
function SizeButtonStyle(el) {
  if(el.id == 'xs'){
    el.style.color = "rgb(0, 35, 102)";
    el.style.backgroundColor = "white";
    document.getElementById('s').style.color = "white";
    document.getElementById('s').style.backgroundColor = "rgb(0, 35, 102)";
    document.getElementById('m').style.color = "white";
    document.getElementById('m').style.backgroundColor = "rgb(0, 35, 102)";
    document.getElementById('l').style.color = "white";
    document.getElementById('l').style.backgroundColor = "rgb(0, 35, 102)";
    document.getElementById('xl').style.color = "white";
    document.getElementById('xl').style.backgroundColor = "rgb(0, 35, 102)";
   }
}
```

```html
<button id="xs" onclick="SizeButtonStyle(this)" class="size_button"><b>XS</b></button>
<button id="s" onclick="SizeButtonStyle(this)" class="size_button"><b>S</b></button>
<button id="m" onclick="SizeButtonStyle(this)" class="size_button"><b>M</b></button>
<button id="l" onclick="SizeButtonStyle(this)" class="size_button"><b>L</b></button>
<button id="xl" onclick="SizeButtonStyle(this)" class="size_button"><b>XL</b></button>
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no clicked property. So you would have to listen to the click event listener and see what element was clicked.

```js
function SizeButtonStyle (button) {

  // remove the class of the previous selected element
  var selected = document.querySelector('.size_button.selected')
  if (selected) {
    selected.classList.remove('selected')
  }
  button.classList.add('selected')
  return false
}
```

```css
.size_button {
  display: inline-block;
  background: #000;
  border-radius: .2em;
  font-family: "arial-black";
  font-size: 1em;
  min-width: 2em;
  color: #FFF;
  padding: .5em;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-align: center;
}

.size_button.selected {
  background-color: #16a975;
  color: #fbca01;
}
```

```html
<button id="xs" onclick="return SizeButtonStyle(this)" class="size_button"><b>XS</b></button>
<button id="s" onclick="return SizeButtonStyle(this)" class="size_button"><b>S</b></button>
<button id="m" onclick="return SizeButtonStyle(this)" class="size_button"><b>M</b></button>
<button id="l" onclick="return SizeButtonStyle(this)" class="size_button"><b>L</b></button>
<button id="xl" onclick="return SizeButtonStyle(this)" class="size_button"><b>XL</b></button>
```

How I would do it is with a radio button list. No JavaScript is needed and it is simple to update and maintain.

```css
[name="size"] {
  display: none;
}

[name="size"] + label {
  display: inline-block;
  background: #000;
  border-radius: .2em;
  font-family: "arial-black";
  font-size: 1em;
  min-width: 2em;
  color: #FFF;
  padding: .5em;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-align: center;
}

[name="size"]:checked + label {
  background-color: #16a975;
  color: #fbca01;
}
```

```html
<input type="radio" id="xs" value="xs" name="size" /><label for="xs">XS</label>
<input type="radio" id="s" value="s" name="size" /><label for="s">S</label>
<input type="radio" id="m" value="m" name="size" /><label for="m">M</label>
<input type="radio" id="l" value="l" name="size" /><label for="l">L</label>
<input type="radio" id="xl" value="xl" name="size" /><label for="xl">XL</label>
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope this solutions suits you well. I've added an event listener that toggles a class where you can control the styling:

```js
let buttons = Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName("size_button"));

buttons.forEach( (button) => {
  button.addEventListener("click", function(){
    this.classList.contains("buttonToggled") ?
      this.classList.remove("buttonToggled") :
      this.classList.add("buttonToggled");
  });
})
```

```css
.buttonToggled {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
        <button class="size_button"><b>XS</b></button>
        <button class="size_button"><b>S</b></button>
        <button class="size_button"><b>M</b></button>
        <button class="size_button"><b>L</b></button>
        <button class="size_button"><b>XL</b></button>
```

Regards!

Answer (score 0):

> Try with this, using class in Jquery

```js
$(document).ready(function(){    
  $(".size_button").click(function(){
   $( ":button" ).css('backgroundColor','rgb(0, 35, 102)')
   $(this).css('backgroundColor','')
 })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="xs" class="size_button"><b>XS</b></button>
<button id="s" class="size_button"><b>S</b></button>
<button id="m" class="size_button"><b>M</b></button>
<button id="l" class="size_button"><b>L</b></button>
<button id="xl" class="size_button"><b>XL</b></button>
```

> using button element in Jquery

```js
 

$(document).ready(function(){
   $("button").on("click",function(){     
       $( ":button" ).css('backgroundColor','rgb(0, 35, 102)')
       $(this).css('backgroundColor','')
    });    
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="xs" class="size_button"><b>XS</b></button>
<button id="s" class="size_button"><b>S</b></button>
<button id="m" class="size_button"><b>M</b></button>
<button id="l" class="size_button"><b>L</b></button>
<button id="xl" class="size_button"><b>XL</b></button>
```